# Is there a best practice to manage the tombstone state in a Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, tombstone

When A WP7 app goes into tombstone state, it is my responsibility to save all the application and page state.  That way when the page gets reloaded it can recover and reload the previous data without the user realizes that the application process got terminated and reloaded.

Coming from the Android world, I am a new WP7 programmer and don't want to have to reinvent the wheel.

Is there a standard way to handle the tombstone state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the application frameworks like [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) have built in tombstone support to help you along.

If you're not using a framework like this then I have heard good things (but not personally used) a library named [Tombstone Helper](http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/) that could help you out.